# Ajax call from an external js file not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

```
$(function() {
  $('.plan_sales').on('change', function() {
    var plan_status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: '/plan_status_update',
      data: {
        'plan_status': plan_status,
        'id': id,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        location.reload();
      }
    });
  })
});
```

Ii am executing this Ajax call and is working well while in the blade file but now I want to have it in an external js file custom.js but it doesn't work. WhenI execute it calls like three different time as show below which I don't understand why. I understand there some tricks one need to do for it to work externally but have tried and is not working.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the initial load of the page (the 200) and then a login (the GET) _is that an ajax call to?_ and then the `plan_status_update` from the code you show us. Am I wring

Comment: "I understand there some tricks one need to do for it to work externally" — There really aren't.

Answer (score 0):

> "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"

Your HTML is being generated by a blade template.

One of the things you are doing with your Blade is injecting a string into the data you are posting with Ajax.

When you move your JavaScript to an external file, you are taking it out of your Blade file and into a stand-alone JS file which isn't generated by the Blade.

This means instead of sending your CSRF token, you are sending the literal string `"{{ csrf_token() }}"` which the server is then rejecting because it isn't the CSRF token.

You need to move `"{{ csrf_token() }}"` to some other part of your Blade file (e.g. a meta tag or data attribute) and change the JavaScript so it reads it from the HTML DOM.